# MySQL query to get top seller

Tags: mysql, sql

Which seller had the most sales of a given products list?

I have 2 tables

**seller_table** :

`id | seller_name`

**sold_products**

(Please note in sold_products there can be multiple entries for same `product_name`  , same `seller_id` but different `quantity_sold`):

```
id | seller_id | product_name | quantity_sold
1  | 1         | cabbage      | 4
1  | 1         | cabbage      | 6
1  | 3         | cabbage      | 1
1  | 3         | cabbage      | 3
1  | 1         | tomatoes     | 4
1  | 1         | tomatoes     | 2
1  | 1         | potatoes     | 4
1  | 3         | tomatoes     | 1
1  | 3         | tomatoes     | 1
1  | 3         | potatoes     | 2
```

I want to get the seller who sold the most of these given item names :
`potatoes, tomatoes, cabbage`, so these must be included in WHERE clause or another way.

Comment: What is your MySQL version?

Comment: Mysql version 5.7.25

Answer (score 2):

```
select seller_id
from sold_products
where product_name in ('potatoes', 'tomatoes', 'cabbage')
group by seller_id
order by sum(quantity_sold) desc
limit 1
```

Comment: That order by sum did it , thanks a bunch , never used it that way! 
Thanks again !

Comment: @alinrazvan note that this doesn't account for ties

Comment: @juergen-d noted , thanks !

Comment: "from seller_table" , i think was meant to be "from sold_products" based on the given table structure above , you can change it if you wish , just a notice.

Answer (score 1):

I think jürgen nailed it. but here are my 2 cents using a subquery:

```sql
SELECT seller_id, sum(quantity_sold)
FROM (SELECT * FROM sellers 
       WHERE product_name in ('cabbage', 'potatoes'))
GROUP BY seller_id;
```

```
1,14
3,6
```

Comment: Thanks for your time , is always good to see other ways to do it .